# Cannot be cast the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, casting, android-context

I've got a little problem casting an activity and when I click the item in my menu to open the activity the app crashes and the logcat says that it can be cast the activity. The problem is in this line:

```
 _Sapp = (SecondActivityApp)getApplicationContext();
```

I think it's the `getApplicationContext` but I'm not sure. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace and what type is `_Sapp` declared as?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: This is how is declared `private SecondActivityApp _Sapp = null;`

Comment: How is SecondActivityApp defined?  Is it a Context?

Comment: Have i to open the activity with a Intent?

Comment: None?:( it's important

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to start a new Activity from the menu, you'll have to use an Intent just like you would, if you wanted to start an activity from any other place.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_testdone:
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivityApp.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I belive you need to add some more information/details about what it is you are trying to do, otherwise I don't understand you question.

Comment: i have created an application with an HomeActivity (that's my MainActivity) with a "call" to another activity as I written in my first post.I thought that only coping the activities in another application and starting the HomeActivity clicking an item in menu, could go but when I click the item I've got the error.so I think the error it's the way I call the activity because I have an error in my logcat "cannot be cast the activity HomeActivity" and the cause is in line 39 of HomeActivity and it's exactly that code I wrote before.understand now?

Comment: So you are trying to start an Activity in another app?